# Call code behind method by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new and I have no idea how to call a code-behind method using javascript. My code is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       function TestCodeBehind() {
           $("Button1").click();           
       }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="TestCodeBehind()"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Code behind:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "PPPP";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually in this example you don't call the onclick event in your own javascript. This event is automatically wired up for you, thus your button should say:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

This will fire the event and run the code in the code behind.

Comment: Actually i want to validate a form before sending to the server can you help that how can i do? @Jeggs

Comment: It sounds like you want to use validation controls, have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542(v=vs.100).aspx) You can either do this in ASP or you can run the form without server side controls and use client javascript to validate, you would then need to post the form using ajax etc (use jQuery or native javascript to achieve this etc). Create a generic handler to read in the form data once it has been posted.